# What makes one relation stronger than another?

Tags: relations

I'm trying to remember a shorthand for a binary relation on relations: Suppose relation $R_2$ contains every tuple that is in $R_1$, and at least one additional tuple.  Do we say "$R_2$ is **stronger than** $R_1$," or is there some other term that should be used?

Comment: [see here](https://books.google.com/books?id=RM1D3mFw2u0C&pg=PA164&lpg=PA164&dq=finer+relation+coarser+math&source=bl&ots=jmankTMdX4&sig=ACfU3U2CpP2M_CBn_65HlCkMM0A_sX6Cqg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiDmIzchN_1AhUkTt8KHZxCBG4Q6AF6BAgsEAM#v=onepage&q=finer%20relation%20coarser%20math&f=false).  This book does use "stronger" / "weaker" to compare relations while it uses "finer" / "coarser" to compare partitions.

Comment: Interestingly though, that cited passage indicates that it $S$ is stronger than $R$ iff $S\subset R$, so the meaning you wish to apply to "stronger" vs "weaker" is flipped.  In terms of analogy, "Two people live in the same city" is a stronger piece of information to know than "Two people live in the same country."  As such, in your example we should have said $R_2$ is *weaker* than $R_1$.

Comment: And that passage provides a definition only for _equivalence_ relations.

Comment: Read further.  "2.10 Definition: Let $R$ and $S$ be two binary relations on a set $X$.  Then $S$ is said to be **stronger** than $R$ (or $R$ is said to be weaker than $S$) if for all $x,y\in X,~xSy$ implies $xRy$."  It stated binary relations here, it did not specify equivalence relations.

Comment: @JMoravitz ah perfect, that's exactly what I was hoping for.  Care to make an answer so I can upvote and accept?

Comment: @JMoravitz BTW the reason I didn't spot it is that Google's preview doesn't show me those pages. I get page 164 and then the next page I am permitted to see is page 168, and they are up to Proposition 2.14.  I wonder why you get to see those pages and I don't?

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the comments, $R_1$ is stronger than $R_2$ if $x\,R_1\,y$ implies $x\,R_2\,y$.

Why people so persistently put answers in comments is something I'll never understand.

Comment: I agree about answers in the comments.